# Please help solving variables with conditions

Tags: inequality

I am seeking for a method that automatically solves variables (find out values of variables). Here I have a problem with 4 variables:

With 0 < {og, bg, s, h} < 100 (each variable larger than 0 and smaller than 100)

```
og + h <= bg
og + s <= bg
og + s +h >= bg
og < bg
bg + h > og
bg + s + h > og
s < bg
s <= og
s + h <= og
h < og
h < bg
```

How to solve values of those variables? The closer the better.
Thank you.

Comment: What is a "valuable"? Most of your inequalities are redundant. Do you want to isolate the ones that are not redundant?

Comment: I think "valuable" is something like a number, a digit, that is, in the set of the real numbers (float variable type), between 0 and 100, and with those conditions (inequalities) each variable holds which number? For example ```og=37.5```. And I am seeking for an automatical method, like, solve by a computer. So I guess the input should be the more specific the better, though, you are right that is redundant.

Comment: An automatic method to do what? There are infinitely many values for (og,bg,s,h) which satisfy the inequalities.

Comment: Ah, value, I forgot that word, sorry. Thank you for answering. Could you please tell, to find the most exact values for those variables, which type of condition must be added there that I perhaps don't know of?

Comment: There are 393,089 solutions for which all variables are integers.  Which one(s) do you want?

Comment: Thank you for that statistic. Perhaps it is basically the same, but if I smaller the range from the scale of 100 to the scale of 10, will it solvable? I am finding how to solve this type of problem, because if the quantity of variables increase, there will be many more solutions, that I don't think any of us will sit down and solve it.. I didn't mean to present a problem that looks like a joke to you, but I only have those data: the range of each variable and the relationships of them. I am asking for the way to solve, or how to make the range of searching smaller.